# getting table name from a table and using the table name to access data

Tags: mysql, database, select

I want to create a database where there is a list of table names stored in a table. Now with the help of this list I can access the other tables.

Ex :-

```
Table name :- table_list (2 column i.e. table_name,table_id)
table_list attributes 
authentication 1 
basic_info 2 
contact 3
```

I can directly access these tables using select statement but I want to access them using the table_list table preferably using select statement.

I tried

```
select * from (select table_name as x from table_list where id=2) as y
```

But could not get the proper output.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?Whats the point of storing table name in another table.If its for security purpose,you can create views and give limited access to users.

Comment: For my project I have already created views. But I wanted to achieve some dynamic approach to retrieve data from various tables. Also this method can provide security which is a plus point.

Answer (score 2):

It is called [`Prepared Statements`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) and their only use is when you want to implement your mentioned need in one request. Otherwise you can easily retrieve table names in a programming language and create your next statement using the data in hand. Here's how `Prepared Statements` work:

```
SELECT table_name INTO @tbl FROM my_tables WHERE id = 1 LIMIT 1;
SET @sql := CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', @tbl);
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have the time to test it. You are right, it's not working. I have updated it now so it works. Thanks to point it out.

Comment: `SELECT getname.tbnm INTO @tbl FROM getname WHERE getname.id = 1 LIMIT 1;
SET @sql := CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', @tbl);
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt1;`
@Mehran I tried your give statement and everything went perfect except for the last `DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;`.

Comment: What was the problem with `DEALLOCATE`? I tried it myself and it works! Perhaps your question is more like what it does? In that case I must say it removes the previously created `Prepared Statement` and you need to call it when you have no longer the need to use the statement. Other than that I don't have any idea what might go wrong with deallocation!

Answer (score 0):

```
TRY THIS

select * from (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM TABLE_LIST WHERE ID=2)as y
```

Comment: This statement will return values from the `TABLE_NAME` column in the `TABLE_LIST`. How is this any different from the query posted by the OP?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are sure that the table name you want to access is x, just check whether such a table exists using a query and use x for future purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The table name (an "identifier") must be a static part of the SQL text issed to the database; the identifier can't be supplied "on the fly", either as a parameter or as a result from another SQL query.

To do what you want to do, you will need a two step approach.  You can use one (or more) SQL statements to obtain the identifiers you need (table name, column names, etc.), and then use that to dynamically create a second SQL statement, as a string.

The identifiers (table names, column anmes) can not be provided as parameters or "bind variables", they must be a static part of the SQL text.

For example, to generate the statement:

```
SELECT CONCAT('SELECT * FROM `',table_name,'` ORDER BY 1') AS stmt
  FROM table_list
 WHERE id = 2
```

(The coding details are dependent on what language you are using.)